# Where to post if questions fit multiple "networks"?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, site-recommendation

I have 3 questions that I don't know where to post on "Stack Overflow".
So asking where to ask seems to me a meta related subject. Is it?

Q1 is mathematically but described programmatically.
Q2/Q3: asking about similar programs.

Best regards.

Q1:
Is there a known function, that is able to "loop" over a 1, 2 or 3 dimensional area, getting all items once, and the returned array looks like randomly, depending on the initialization.

Kind of: ( 1,2,3,4,5,6,7) <-> (5,6,1,2,7,3,4)

The start position should be chosen.
To be clear I don't need a algorithm, that "scramble" an array randomly.

Q2:
Which growl like environment is able to send receive udp-messages and is available for windows, android and linux.

Q3:
is there a rib (https://01.org/rib/online/) like ide in order to create responsive GUI interfaces for mobile devices of differences sizes?

Comment: Q1 probably would get closed as demonstrate minimal understanding of the problem being solved (some people may interpret it as asking for a tool or library etc). 2nd question is off-topic as its asking for a tool recomendation. 3rd question same thing

Comment: I can say that Q1 is likely to fall foul of minimum understanding of the problem to be solved (I.e. try something first) on stack overflow at least Q2 and Q3 are both looking for recomendations which are off topic network wide

Comment: @mehow Great minds think alike

Comment: Ty, I didn't know that there was an off-topic section. An other reason why i asked, is that i got in the past answers, which where not even close related to my question, and far away form being helpful, like: Q: "i like cats, where can i buy a cat?", A: "What about dogs?", A: "less <filename> is much better than cat".

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "off-topic section". If a question is off-topic, it will get closed and deleted from the site.

Answer (score 5):

Questions 2 & 3 are asking for off-site resources. As such, they are off-topic on pretty much all Stack Exchange sites.

Question 1 is missing your efforts - we expect you to **try** something before asking and it shown no effort either it attempting something yourself or researching the problem.

On Stack Exchange sites, we look for questions that are generally answerable, have **definite** answers and that are showing the efforts of the asker to solve them.

Comment: How could i find a mathematical function, if i don't have any idea if it exists ;) It's like ordering food in a foreign language, without an dictionary or even knowing basics, or knowing where to buy a dictionary, ...

Comment: @inselberg - lots of handwaving gets you a long way ;)

Comment: @inselberg Building on your metaphor - A group of linguists probably won't appreciate you going to one of their meetings and asking how to order food in their language, or where to buy a dictionary. You should take a class or look it up and go to a bookstore or library respectively.